# VScode no response when opening PDF

Tags: visual-studio-code

After the recent updates, I experienced a weird bug that sometimes when I open the PDF in VScode, the whole VScode frozen (including other windows). I will need to force quit to restart the VScode.

I've tried several different PDF viewing extensions, but all of them experience the same problem -- so I suspect it might be something related to VScode itself.

Is there anyone who also experiencing the and have the solution? Thank you.

p.s. I'm on M1 Macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a "focus follows mouse" function like yabai?

I was in the exact same situation, but when I stopped yabai, no more problems occurred!

Comment: I do use yabai! Wow this is the most unexpected reason and almost impossible to find out -- thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it's resolved!
Incidentally, if you just want to use the focus follow mouse function, you can use [AutoRaise](https://github.com/sbmpost/AutoRaise).
Nothing wrong with opening pdfs here!

PS: I was a little mistaken, but vscode crashes when I open a pdf even if I turn off most of yabai's features.
So it looks like it's not because of focus_follow_mouse, but rather a mesh with yabai itself...

Answer (score 0):

On Pop!_OS 22.04, the extension [vscode-pdf](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomoki1207.pdf) is not working. But, the [PDF Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=analytic-signal.preview-pdf) extension, is working normally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

until now VSCode continues to try to do the best, one of which is features that can be integrated with PDF
maybe you can check this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomoki1207.pdf

VS Code has built-in debugging support for the Node.js runtime and can debug JavaScript, TypeScript, or any other language that gets transpiled to JavaScript.

For debugging other languages and runtimes (including PHP, Ruby, Go, C#, Python, C++, PowerShell and many others), look for Debuggers extensions in the VS Code Marketplace or select Install Additional Debuggers in the top-level Run menu.

Below are several popular extensions which include debugging support (click below) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjeCC.png)